# How to trigger dropdownlist's SelectedIndexChanged event by clicking enter or left mouse down?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist on a page like this;

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCities" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCities_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This works great in normal conditions. But I have to change behaviour of dropdownlist due to client's actions.

So I mean, when client focused dropdownlist and moved down to other list items, `SelectedIndexChanged` event is triggered. But I don't want this. I want, when user focused an element of dropdownlist, `SelectedIndexChanged` event **will not be** triggered, and pressing enter or left mouse down events will trigger `SelectedIndexChanged` event only.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this client side if you have jQuery. Asp.NET Dropdownlist is rendered as a HTML select element.

Haven't tested this, but I think you can prevent the postback in the change event, and trigger it on enter key down...

```
$("#idofselectelement").change(function(e) {
  // This stops auto postback, so SelectedIndexChanged does not fire.
  e.preventDefault();
});



$("#idofselectelement").keyup(function(e) {
     //Check for enter keypress
     if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 13){
            //Simulate autopostback, this triggers SelectedIndexChanged
            __doPostBack('idofselectelement','')    });

     }
```

In my opinion, sometimes it's far more easier to put this functionality in js or jQuery code, because you can directly manipulate the behaviour of the controls, and you are not limited to the functionality that Asp.NET gives you. Don't know how other people think of this??

EDIT: Not tested, but I think event 1 is for right mouseclick....

```
$("#idofselectelement").mousedown(function(event) {
   if(event.which == 1) {
       //Simulate autopostback, this triggers SelectedIndexChanged
        __doPostBack('idofselectelement','')                      
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, I'am using jQuery in my project, I will try this now and give a feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: Dude, this works great when pressing enter. But also I need to trigger left mousedown click. How?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at key hooks to try and do this, that will be your answer.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: I didn't understand, sorry.

Comment: Edited to put a link in to help understand, you want to use key hooks which listen for the end user to press the specified keys,